# JSON.parse: Unexpected EOF in react native, only on app startup

Tags: json, react-native, async-await, expo

I've got an issue in my React Native expo app that only seems to happen when I close and reopen the app. I believe I have valid json and the issue doesn't seem to happen unless the app is starting up. The error message I get is `JSON.parse: Unexpected EOF`. The error comes from this function:

```
  const getEventLabel = (pk) => {
      const event_label = JSON.parse(labelsReference).find(item => item.pk == pk) //error thrown here
      return event_label.title
  }
```

The thing is, if I comment out everything in the `getEventLabel` function and just return "test", the app works fine. I can then comment my original code back in, and the app works as expected. This is how `eventLabelsReference` is assigned:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      getData().then((value) => {
          fetch(`${MY_API}/home/${value?.username}`, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
             "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
     })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
    .then(async (res) => {
      const response = await res.json();
      const eventLabelsReference = JSON.parse(response).labels_reference;
      //console.log('LABELS REFERENCE:')
      //console.log(JSON.parse(labelsReference));
      setEventLabelsReference(JSON.parse(labelsReference))
      setResponse(JSON.parse(response));
    });
});
  }, [navigation]);
```

When printing the `JSON.parse(labelsReference)`, this is what I get:

```
[{"model": "users.label", "pk": 1, "fields": {"title": "Label Name","grade": "9"}}, {"model": "users.label", "pk": 2, "fields": {"title": "test", "grade": "2"}}]
```

When I look up JSON EOF errors, it says to check that I have valid JSON, and I believe that I do. The above JSON is printed whether or not the app has just been loaded.

Let me know if there is any other info I should provide, and any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Since the error is in `JSON.parse(eventLabelsReference)`, the obvious first step is to print `eventLabelsReference`.  I don't understand why you showed us the output of `JSON.parse(labelsReference)` -- how is that relevant?

Comment: @JohnGordon, sorry - had just changed the name and fixed the typo above

Comment: There's no obvious connection between the `labelsReference` variable in the first function, and the `labelsReference` variable in the second function.  They could be completely different variables for all we know.

Comment: There's not even any obvious connection between those two functions.  They don't call each other.  How are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be encountering an issue with the timing of fetching and parsing your JSON data. The error message **"JSON.parse: Unexpected EOF"** typically indicates that the JSON data being parsed is incomplete or malformed.

One possibility is that the **eventLabelsReference** is not being set properly before the **getEventLabel** function is called. This could happen if the fetch call inside the ***useEffect*** hook takes longer to complete than the rendering of the component.

To ensure that **eventLabelsReference** is set before calling **getEventLabel**, you can add a condition to check if **eventLabelsReference** is truthy before attempting to parse it in the **getEventLabel** function. You can modify your code like this:

```
const getEventLabel = (pk) => {
    if (!eventLabelsReference) {
        return ""; // or any default value you prefer
    }
    const event_label = eventLabelsReference.find(item => item.pk === pk);
    return event_label ? event_label.title : "";
}
```

Additionally, you should make sure that you are handling any potential errors properly in your fetch call. If there's an error during the fetch, the response might not be valid JSON, which could also lead to the `"JSON.parse: Unexpected EOF"` error. You're already logging the error with `console.log(e)`, but you might want to check if there's any specific error happening during the fetch.

Lastly, I noticed a potential typo in your **useEffect** hook where you're setting `eventLabelsReference`:

```
setEventLabelsReference(JSON.parse(labelsReference))
```

It seems like you meant to use **eventLabelsReference** instead of **labelsReference**. Make sure to correct that if it's indeed a mistake.

By making these adjustments, you should be able to handle the timing issues and ensure that your JSON data is properly parsed without encountering the **"JSON.parse: Unexpected EOF"** error.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response!! I actually ended up doing   `if(typeof(labelsReference) == 'object') { return ""; }` since it is originally assigned to an object by the React.useState([]).